# strip left and right in php

Tags: php, python, regex

I am converting the following python into php

the aim is to remove scores from a string like "Liverpool 1 v 0 Everton"

```
home, away = event_data.get("desc").split(' v ')

# remove scores from event desc
if home.rsplit(' ', 1)[1].isdigit() and away.split(' ', 1)[0].isdigit():
    event_name = home.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + " v " + away.split(' ', 1)[1]
```

in php so far

```
$nameArray = explode(' v ', $value['name']);

$home = $nameArray[0];
$away = $nameArray[1];

$event_name = $home . ' v ' . $away;
```

im struggling with the stipping the scores, any tips?

Comment: Here s a question I answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676490/php-explode-using-1-fixed-character-and-2-random-numbers/34676704#34676704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `preg_repalce` in PHP you can replace digits around `" v "`:

```
$str = "Liverpool 1 v 0 Everton";

$event_name = preg_replace('/\h+\d+\h+v\h+\d+\h+/', ' v ', $str);

echo $event_name . "\n";
//=> Liverpool v Everton
```

Comment: what about `$str = "Liverpool U23 1 v 0 Everton U23";` ?

Comment: just "Liverpool U23 v Everton U23" without the scores

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/\h+\d+\h+v\h+\d+\h+/', ' v ', "Liverpool U23 1 v 0 Everton U23");` gets me `Liverpool U23 v Everton U23` which is same as what you expect.